# Calling an instance of a class from onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this inside my html file:

```
<div class="messages">
      <input id="msg" type="text" name="fname">
      <input type="submit" onclick="general.add.call()" value="Send">
      <input type="submit" onclick="viewMsgs()" value="view messages">
    </div>
```

and in my js file

```
(function(){
  var general = new Channel();
  var rich = new Person('Rich');
  var rob = new Person('Rob');
  var message = new Message(rich, rob, "Hello!");
})()
```

and above that I have:

```
class Channel {
  constructor() {
    this.messages = [];
  }
  add(msg) {
    this.messages.push(msg)
  }
```

why is it saying that `general` is undefined?

Comment: It's because you nested the entire variable decleration inside `function(){` for some reason

Comment: Variables live within an execution context. *general* exists within the execution context that it was declared, i.e. of the IIFE `(function(){...})()`, and can't be accessed from outside.

Answer (score 1):

`general` is a local variable that exists *only inside* the IIFE that you wrapped around your code.

It isn't a global, so you can't access it as a global.

Bind your event handler using `addEventListener` (inside the IIFE) instead of using an `onclick` attribute.